# How to retrieve Data from Php while in Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, node.js, ajax

I just wanted to retrieve some PHP/Mysql stuff at the beginning of my app (authentication and x and y data) from the users which I later plan to emit to the `app.js` (one time at the beginning and once the user disconnects update `x - y` values).

So basically I have set up Nodes.js and understood that some stuff is not possible like before (e.g with plain php)

Where I already have a problem is the AJAX php request in the index.html of my nodes Server

Schema:

`app.js`: pull Data from the `/Client/index.html`  (I think need to do it via sockets)

`index.html`: get or post data via Ajax to a php file and get the values of the database back to the `index.html`(JavaScript) 
then send that data via sockets to the `app.js`

php: select mysql database
retrieve values from mysql
parse them via Json and make them available in the `index.html` file Nodes.js (Client)

Maybe somebody of you have a solution

Nodes.js `/Client/index.html`:

```
function checkuser(username, password) {
    var myObj;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
            myObj = xhttp.responseText;
            var i = 0;
            while (i <= myObj.length) {
                //console.log("ASQL found and Auth Username:"+ myObj[i].username)  ;
                console.log(myObj.username);
                i++;
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/client/is_user.php?username333=" + username + "&password333=" + password, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

`is_user.php`:

```
<?php
require('config_sql.php');
$email = stripslashes($_GET['username333']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
$password369 = stripslashes($_GET['password333']);
$password369 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password369);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='$email'
and password='".md5($password369)."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
$response = array();
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while ($row_user= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $response[] = $row;
}
$jsonData = json_encode($response); 
echo $jsonData;
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

atm is not retrieving the username form the created json on the php side. 
If  I `console.log(myObj);` it's showing the me complete php.file data as plain text if I want to retrieve the username from MySql its saying `undefined`.

Is the php Interpreter actually working when I `post/get` via Ajax in a Node.js environment?
Normally when I was programming with pure php all the request worked well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not do it all in node instead?

Comment: **Warning:** Don't use `md5()` for password hashing. It's very insecure. When using PHP, use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. You shouldn't escape the passwords before hashing them either. That actually changes the passwords.

Comment: You should also use POST when sending user credentials instead of GET (since that sends the username and password in clear text in the URL).

Comment: Why not in nodes ? I dont want to show my mysql login data to everybody as javascript sourcecode can be seen by everybody?

Comment: Node is server side so people won't be able to access that code. It's only the client side javascript that people can see and that's not where you would put any mysql credentials.

Comment: Ok that makes alot of things easier I thought it is viewable

Comment: I would recommend checking out some tutorials. It will probably make things more clear.

Comment: Magnus then just one more questions . I have a synology Server that running mysql in behind. Do I still need to install mysql like npm install mysql or can i directly use my js within the App.js – sorry i am not a pro with all that putty and Linux stuff

Comment: MySQL is just a database server and doesn't have anything to do with node, PHP or anything. All you're doing in your application is connecting to the database server. You can use any programming language to connect to the same server as long as you have the correct client libraries for that language. The database server can be anywhere.

Comment: You have a lot security bug in your code!

Answer (score 0):

Check you code for recieving result from query:

```
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while ($row_user= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$response[] = $row;
}
```

$jsonData = json_encode($response);

Should be so:

```
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while ($row_user= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$response[] = $row_user;
}
```

$jsonData = json_encode($response);